# Cap or cover for Dual Kitchen Sink Waste

Tags: plumbing, kitchens

I've just bought a house which has one of these dual wastes for connecting a washing machine and dishwasher

[image]

However we only need one now as we only have a washing machine where this sink is so I want to find a cap for the remaining one.

The pipe seems to be about 29mm and the connector about 33m but I can't find any corresponding caps for this, can anyone shed any light on what might solve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: I can't see your image. Please post it to a non-commercial photo share site or upload it here.

Answer (score 2):

The likely "best" solution is to replace the dual-port entry piece with a single-port entry piece. No extra hose port, no need to plug an extra hose port. Hang the dual there in case you ever want to have two in the future.

Either that, or take out the dual-port entry for long enough to take a field-trip with it to a hardware or plumbing supply store to seek out a suitable cap that fits. Given that these are hose ports, not standard pipes, if you can't get a cap made for where the hose-adapter-swivel part is, an official cap to fit is going to be uncommon, IME. But perhaps you'll get lucky.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest might be to install a short section of hose to fit the inlet you aren't using, and then plug that.

Answer (score 0):

The slip-joint connection inboard of both those hose connections should be 1 1/2" pipe thread. Simply disconnect at the joint and thread an 1 1/2" PVC or ABS cap on there, with a couple turns of teflon tape on the threads.